# Using useRef hook with React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-admin

I try to create a reference to a React-Admin element using the useRef hook, but I do not succeed.

Same doing with native react.js works fine using a simple `<input>` field, but with a react-admin component the reference is null.

Anyone knows how to reference an element in react-admin ?

```
const myForm = (props) => {

    const refContainer = useRef(null);

    const myClick = () => {
        console.log('clicked !', refContainer); // refContainer is null !!!
        refContainer.current.value = '1';
    };
    return <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source='myValue' ref={refContainer} value='0'/>
        <input type="button" value="change" onClick={myClick}/></SimpleForm>
    </Edit>;
};
```

Comment: why not set it via state? create a state that holds the value and change it in 'myClick'. If you want to change only text you can try: "refContainer.current.setNativeProps({ text: '1' })"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use instead ref: `inputRef` https://material-ui.com/ru/api/input/

```
<TextField inputRef={refContainer} />
```

Comment: This is correct.  React-admin's TextInput passes the inputRef prop through to Material-UI's TextField.  Thanks @MaxAlex.